# Can fs write to a user's *local* file system from a *deployed* node.js app?

Tags: node.js, heroku, fs

Can fs write to a user's *local* file system (like into "Downloads", for example) from a *deployed* node.js app?

I was able to do it when I was running the file locally (localhost:), but the same code won't create the same files when I deploy the code on Heroku. Is it possible at all? If so then I'll keep working on what's maybe a directory/path problem. If not, I'll stop banging my head against the wall!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can fs write to a user's local file system (like into "Downloads", for example) from a deployed node.js app?

No, this is not possible at all.  The server itself cannot directly reach the user's local file system (its on another computer and usually behind one or more firewalls).  In addition, browsers do not allow servers to directly write to the user's local file system via the browser and for a whole host of good security reasons.

Imagine if some random web-site you visit could write to your own local file system.  All sorts of havoc could occur if untrusted servers had the ability to access your local file system.

FYI, there are ways for the user themselves to circumvent these protections, but these all involve the end-user installing software locally on their computer that can do this (such as a browser add-on or some other program that connects to the server and carries out local file system operations on behalf of the server).  Sometimes users are tricked into doing this (e.g. ransomware, viruses) and sometimes there are legitimate, safe apps that do this.  But, it requires the end-user to install additional code on their computer to enable that type of access.

FYI, a server can "offer" a file download via a browser to go into the user's downloads folder on the user's local computer (or whatever folder the end-user chooses), but this still requires end-user confirmation and cannot be done in the browser without the end-users participation.  If the server sends the right type of response to a browser request, then the browser will prompt the user for a download.

Comment: Thank you very much. So it's not just my incompetence!  :) . I'm drawing a blank now, what sort of server response could trigger a browser to ask a user if they want to download? I know that's a "thing", but I'm drawing a blank on how I initiate it. Thanks again, jfriend00 for the great answer!

Comment: @DesmondMullen - I think you're probably looking for `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.jpg"` in the response header to tell the browser that this response is recommended as a file download.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you, I wasn't previously familiar with that. That will at least partially solve the challenge. Thanks again @jfriend00, this has been super-helpful!